# Django 3.2.3 trying to access admin url getting 403 CSRF verification failed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**The error that I'm getting.**

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.
```

**Settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False # Hosted with Apache 2 with no SSL.
```

I'm trying to access my admin section.

Comment: Share the full error, is it the CSRF_DOMAIN or CSRF not present issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby CSRF cookie not set.